# Dynamic options in select showing empty text between two elements

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 <select name="QuestionType" data-validation-required-message="Choose the Question Type" class="form-control">
                        <?php
                        foreach ($drpquestiontype as $row) {
                            $QuestionTypeId = $row['QuestionTypeId'];
                            $QuestionTypeName = $row['QuestionTypeName'];

                            echo '<option value='.$QuestionTypeId.'>'.$QuestionTypeName.'<option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
```

**Please help**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line has missing quotes. The single quotes break you out of the echo command, so the resulting html has no quotes around the value attribute. You're also missing a slash on the closing option tag. This:

```
 echo '<option value='.$QuestionTypeId.'>'.$QuestionTypeName.'<option>';
```

Generates this:

```
'<option value=6>Name<option>';
```

The PHP code should be:

```
echo '<option value="'.$QuestionTypeId.'">'.$QuestionTypeName.'</option>';
```

Comment: @vini No problem. If you could accept my answer, that would be most appreciated. Thanks.